# portable class library and System.Type with missing methods

Tags: c#, xamarin, portable-class-library

I'm trying to implement MonkeyArms into a portable class library in Xamarin for a multiplatform application. However, I seem to be running into a build issue.

I receive the error

```
Type 'System.Type' does not contain a definition for GetInterfaces 
and no extension method GetInterfaces of type 'System.Type' 
could be found, are you missing an assembly reference.
```

Has anyone come up against this issue with other Nuget Packages and if so what was your solution. Or is this just an issue with the portable class library being minimal in nature.

Answer (score 2):

For maximum portability, instead try using:

```
var myInterfaces = myType.GetTypeInfo().GetInterfaces();
```

The .NET Portability Analyzer tool usually gives some good hints for equivalent code when APIs are not directly supported across all .NET target platforms.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/08/06/leveraging-existing-code-across-net-platforms/